# Fluent expression helper for reading public const and static fields/properties

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

Does anyone know how to write an ExpressionHelper.GetName method so I can get the name of a public static/const property or field using Reflection and C# 3.0

So for

```
static class B
{
  public const string Field = "mittens";
  public static string Prop = "the kitten";
}
```

The following asserts would work (the syntax is obviously not going to work)

```
Assert.AreEqual(ExpressionHelper.GetName(B.Field),"Field");
Assert.AreEqual(ExpressionHelper.GetName(B.Prop),"Prop");
```

The important thing is for compile time errors to appear when someone changes these fields/props.

Thanks!

Comment: Won't happen for the constants because they'll get burnt into call sites at compile time.. you could get fields and properties etc using lambda expressions so the syntax would be GetName(() => B.Field)

Comment: Thanks meandmycode you should write an answer

Answer (score 1):

The article [LINQ beyond queries: strong-typed reflection](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2006/07/06/Linq-beyond-queries_3A00_-strong_2D00_typed-reflection_2100_.aspx) could offer a solution. I read it several months ago - so I cannot offer a definit solution at the moment. But may be it helps.